# Red-blue alternating paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, tag-removed

Suppose we have two simple graphs on the same vertex set. We will call one of them red, the other blue. Suppose that for $i=1,..,k$ we have $deg (v_i)\ge i$ in both graphs, where $V_k=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a subset of the vertices. Is it always possible to find a family of vertex disjoint paths such that

1. for $i=1,.., k$ every $v_i$ is contained in a path,
2. each path consists of vertices only from $V_k$ except for exactly one of its endpoints which must be outside of $V_k$,
3. in each path the red and blue edges are alternating?

The claim is true if $k$ is small (<6). It is also true if the red graph and the blue graph are the same. This question was brought to my attention by a few friends who could use it in one of their papers in preparation.

**Update 2015.06.26** As there is renewed interest, let me add that here is the since then published paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0642 and last year the claim for which they needed this lemma was solved in another way by Gyarfas: http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/dmgt.2014.34.issue-1/dmgt.1735/dmgt.1735.xml.

Comment: Is the condition that $\deg(v_i)\geq i$ of special importance? It seems a bit surprising, is this sharp in some sense?

Comment: @Per: Yes. Suppose both graphs are the same and the vertex set is $v_1, \ldots, v_k, u_1, \ldots, u_k$ and the edges are $v_iu_j$ if and only if $i\le j$. In this case the only solution is to take all $k$ single-edge paths $v_iu_i$. If you delete any of these edges, the statement becomes false.

Comment: @Per: On the other hand, maybe it is enough to demand one degree less in, say, the blue graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think even the stronger lemma is true where all paths will be edges:

Let $G$ be a simple graph, $V_k=\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ a subset of vertices and we have $deg(v_i)\geq i$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$. Then there is a matching which covers $V_k$.

PROOF:

If there is no edge between vertices from $V_k$ (so $V_k$ is stable) then we can consider only the edges between $V_k$ and $V\setminus V_k$ (the induced bipartite graph between $V_k$ and $V\setminus V_k$). The degree of the vertices from $V_k$ in this bipartite graph will be the same as in the original graph, so the condition still holds. From this it follows that $V_k$ satisfies the condition of Hall's marriage theorem thus there is a matching covering $V_k$. Indeed, let $X\subseteq V_k$, and let $v_l\in X$ be the vertex with the highest index in $X$. Then $|X|\leq l$. On the other hand all the neighbors of $v_l$ are in the neighborhood of $X$ so $deg(v_l)\leq |N(X)|$. Combining these two observation with our condition of $deg(v_l)\geq l$ we get that $|X|\leq |N(X)|$

If there is an edge $(v_iv_j)$, where $v_i,v_j\in V_k$, then let's choose such an edge where the sum of indexes $i+j$ is the smallest possible and suppose that $i<j$. Let's delete $v_i$ and $v_j$ from the graph. All the other vertices from $V_k$ can have their degree decrease with at most 2. If the degree of $v_l$ decreases by 1 then $v_l$ is a neighbor of $v_i$ or $v_j$ and because of $i+j$ being minimal we have $i<l$. If the degree of $v_l$ decreases by 2 then $v_l$ is a neighbor of both $v_i$ and $v_j$, and again, using that $i+j$ is minimal we have $i<j<l$. This means that by adjusting the indexes for the remaining vertices in $V_k$ in the natural way ($v_l$ remains $v_l$ if $l<i$, is renamed to $v_{l-1}$ if $i<l<j$ and is renamed to $v_{l-2}$ if $j<l$), the $V_{k-2}$ we got like this satisfies the degree condition $deg(v_i)\geq i$ for all index $i$. By induction we are done in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately we also need that one endpoint of each path is outside $V_k$, your construction does not satisfy this, as both endpoints of the matching might be in $V_k$.

Comment: Let me simplify the proof of David's theorem. On $i$-th step we choose an edge $v_iu_i$ from the vertex $v_i$ by the following algorithm. If $v_i$ is already covered, go to next step. If we may choose edge $v_iv_j$, do it with minimal possible $j$. If not, but we may choose edge $v_iu$, $u\notin V_k$, do it. What if we can't? It means that all edges to $v_i$ go to vertices $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1},u_1,\dots,u_{i-1}$. But if $u_j\notin \{v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}\}$, then $v_i$ has at most 1 neighbor in $\{v_j,u_j\}$ by our construction. Using this and $deg(v_i)\geq i$ we see that we really may proceed.